# How to detect whether a SynchronizationContext serializes operations?

Tags: .net, synchronizationcontext

I have library code that relies on a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (provided by the application) to serialize some operations and execute them on the same thread. This library code is agnostic about the application that it will run in.

However, only some implementations of `SynchronizationContext` will do this, like [`WindowsFormSynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx), [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and possibly others that I don't know about.

Other implementations like the base `SynchronizationContext` itself and `AspNetSynchronizationContext` are free-threaded; they will not do serialization of operations.

If my code gets handed a `SynchronizationContext`, how can it distinguish between these two cases? I want it to fail fast with a clear error if the synchronization context is not appropriate.

Comment: It is beyond your control and unknowable, although the world isn't exactly awash in them.  If you want a guarantee then you must use Send() instead of Post().